# Dataloader fails to insert data due to different date format

Tags: data-loader, date

I am loading data from a CSV file to my salesforce org using **Dataloader.io**.

One of the fields for the record is a date field. In my salesforce org I have **changed the time zone to (GMT+05:30) India Standard Time (Asia/Kolkata)**, my locale to **English (India)** for System Admin, Company Information and Personal Information.

So as expected the date formats are **DD/MM/YYYY**. In my CSV file, the date field has **DD/MM/YYYY** format as well.

However when I do an insert using Dataloader.io it throws an error saying

> DESTINATION: `Date_Field__c` is not a valid DATE.[VALID date format:
>   MM/DD/YYYY].

This single issue causes entire rows to fail. Any idea how I would solve this issue? Do I need to change anything in **Dataloader.io**?

Comment: Can u post here any sample date from your csv file so that we can know the exact format of it ? Also are you dealing with huge number of records ?

Comment: @Ruchi I am dealing with 1282 records. The sample data is just 3 text fields, one checkbox (boolean) and one date field that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dataloader.io has an advanced settings pain on the run page of their wizard.

You can change the expected day-month order here.

[image: Set date format]

Most Salesforce ETL tools have some setting like this.

If that doesn't fix it, then it is likely that something actually wrong with the date format itself, such as the delimiters between the different date elements not being acceptable, or other characters corrupting the date.

For reference here is the full settings pain:

[image]

Comment: That was right there. My bad, should have checked the advance settings. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The standard format for loading date fields is the ISO standard: YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: That's only relevant when using the API. Various tools have different rules about formats they accept.